# Unit testing the effects on an AngularJS $rootScope.$emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, rootscope, emit

I'm writing an AngularJS unit test that emits and event and then calls a service to see if the event was processed correctly.

```
$rootScope.$emit('MY_EVENT');
expect(MyService.foo).toEqual('bar');
```

My service implements the event listener in the conventional manner:

```
//                         function called asynchronously?
$rootScope.$on('MY_EVENT', function(event, result) {
    //do something synchronous
});
```

Though my test currently passes I'm concerned that my event listener is probably being processed asynchronously.

My question is, is calling `$rootScope.$digest()` before my expectation enough to insure that all the event listeners have been called and returned?

Comment: Yes, that is all you need to do.